# Why does putting an SF symbol in a UIImage and then in a SwiftUI Image View result in a blurry image?

Tags: swiftui, uiimage

I'm trying to write a public init that takes a UIImage, but I want to allow both a normal, actual UIImage made from say a photo (or otherwise drawn) OR use the SF Symbols, but I am stumped as to why the SF Symbols are blurred. What am I missing?

Here is the code I've got:

```
struct TempUIImageView: View {

    var defaultImage: UIImage = UIImage(systemName: "globe")!

    var defaultImageString: String = "globe"

    var body: some View {
        VStack  {
            Image(uiImage: defaultImage)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            Image(systemName: defaultImageString)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

i'm hoping to use a solution in this:

```
@State private var displayedImage: UIImage?

...

private var displayImage: some View {
    Image(uiImage: displayedImage!)
        .resizable()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
        .scaledToFill()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .clipShape(Circle())
        .shadow(radius: 4)
}
```

But displayedImage could be a UIImage OR an SF Symbol.

(The forced unwrap is dealt with in other code, but this is preliminary code anyways)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you use `Image(systemName:)` the system draws to the screen using vector graphics, resulting in sharp, un-blurry renderings.

However, `UIImage`, including, it seems `UIImage(systemName:)` is a bitmapped image, at a set resolution. If you scale it up (as you're doing in your second block of code), you'll get blurriness, because you're not getting the benefits of the vector graphics.

Using a pattern like the following would allow you to conditionally display a `Image(uiImage:)` or `Image(systemName:)` and still use the same set of modifiers for each:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var displayedImage : UIImage?
    
    var imageToDisplay: Image {
        if let displayedImage = displayedImage {
            return Image(uiImage: displayedImage)
        } else {
            return Image(systemName: "camera.circle")
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        imageToDisplay
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .frame(width: 400, height: 400)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, if you have the constraint of having to use a `UIImage`, you can scale up an SF Symbol [by using `.applyingSymbolConfiguration`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/configuring_and_displaying_symbol_images_in_your_ui#3880238) and setting a font size & rendering scale.

In your example:

```swift
var defaultImage: UIImage = UIImage(systemName: "globe")!
    .applyingSymbolConfiguration(.init(
        font: .systemFont(ofSize: 64),
        scale: .large
    ))
```

This will render the `UIImage` bitmap at the appropriate size & scale, so it should appear non-blurry. (This will still cause issues on resize, however.)